# Problem with subscribe and callback function

Tags: ros, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
since my code is really long I will try to keep it minimal

in my program I wrote a class which defines 2 storing variables:

```
geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped initial_pose_;
geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped pose;
```

and subscribes to the `/initialpose` topic:

```
ros::topic::waitForMessage<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>( "initialpose", ros::Duration( 60.0 ) );
this->pose_sub_ = nh_.subscribe( "initialpose", 10, updateInitialPose );
```

the callback function has been defined as:

```
void updateInitialPose( const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped::ConstPtr& pose )
{
initial_pose_ = pose;
}
```

but compiling I get all the time the following error:

> /home/wilhem/workspace_ros/src/turtlebot_guide/src/main.cpp: In member function ‘void
> robotMovement::updateInitialPose(const
> ConstPtr&)’:
> /home/wilhem/workspace_ros/src/turtlebot_guide/src/main.cpp:45:17:
> error: no match for ‘operator=’
> (operand types are
> ‘geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped’
> and ‘const ConstPtr {aka const
> boost::shared_ptr<const
> geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped_std::allocator<void
>
> > > }’)    initial_pose_ = pose;
> > > ^ /home/wilhem/workspace_ros/src/turtlebot_guide/src/main.cpp:45:17:
> > > note: candidate is: In file included
> > > from
> > > /home/wilhem/workspace_ros/src/turtlebot_guide/src/main.cpp:10:0:
> > > /opt/ros/indigo/include/geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.h:57:8:
> > > note:
> > > geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped_std::allocator<void
> > > & geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped_std::allocator<void
> > > ::operator=(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped_std::allocator<void
> > > &)  struct PoseWithCovarianceStamped_
> > > ^

Even the candidated definitions are to me not really clear.
I have already searched through the API and class definitions but I couldnt find a solution.
Any help?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191012/problem-with-subscribe-and-callback-function/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to assign a shared pointer `geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceConstPtr` to an instance of `geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped`.

The `operator=` is not overloaded to perform deep copies (AFAIK).

The shared pointer cannot know the structure of the underlying object. A slightly annoying, but easy way of working around that is by copying the data field by field, such as:

```
initial_pose_.header = pose->header;
initial_pose_.pose = pose->pose;
```

Also note that your global variable named `pose` has the same name as the shared pointer (message) received in the callback.

Perhaps you could avoid using global variables in the process of making the necessary changes! :-)

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-22**:
`initial_pose_ = *pose` should also work.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-22**:
It works!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanxxxxxxxxx!!!!
But another question, how should I know that the operator = is not overloaded!?!??!?!!???

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-22**:
From the error you got, it said: `error: no match for ‘operator=’` and showed the object types involved.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-22**:
Thanx Murilo,
could you me explain please what is  boost::shared_ptr ?

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-22**:
I think it is a hard topic to explain in this 'comments area'. Besides that, it falls out of the scope of the original question (we must keep the site tidy). A nice tutorial I read when I first learnt about smart pointers was [this one](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/smart-pointers-in-boost/184401507).